# Should I pass whole object as function parameter?

Tags: php, function, parameters

Assume we have some object

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->b = 7;
$a->c = 'o';
$a->d = array(1,2,3);
```

Also we have a function which doing something with *some of* properties of our object (for example `b` and `d[1]`).

**My question**: Should my function accept whole object as a parameter like:

```
function some($a) {
 var_dump($a->b);
 var_dump($a->d[1]);
}

some($a);
```

or accept only certain fields which it's process like:

```
function some($b, $d) {
 var_dump($b);
 var_dump($d);
}

some($a->b, $a->d[1]);
```

Actually no matter is `$a` object or array.

Comment: Which way makes the code read best in your situation?

Comment: This kind of question is off topic here as there is no 'one clear answer' as you can see already. Please read the [FAQ].

Comment: neither way restricts functionality, so I would design for the common case(maybe calling code usually has objects constructed already, or maybe they dont)

Comment: @Cory Carson It doesn't matter how code reads. I worry about worth it or not passing unnecessary stuff to function. Maybe it takes bit more resources from PHP to process it.

Comment: @vascowhite so where should I ask this kind of question?

Comment: @webbandit objects are passed by reference, so you are not "passing unnecessary stuff", you are only passing a copy of the pointer to the object

Comment: Read the [FAQ] and you will see that the SE sites don't cater for this kind of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the first option is the way to go.

```
function some($a) {
 var_dump($a->b);
 var_dump($a->d[1]);
}

some($a);
```

Because maybe over time you will need other parts of that object/array and you will have to modify the function and the calls where you make them.
So `function some()` can be a global function and used in other ways, you can add later statements, modify the function without having to modify everywhere.

```
function some($a, $param1 = 1){
    if($param1 == 1){
        var_dump($a->c);
        var_dump($a->d[2]);
    } else {
        var_dump($a->b);
        var_dump($a->d[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah man this is probably the best way

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that objects are passed by reference by default, so if you pass the whole object, you can change the objects values from within the function itself if needed.

If passing only some properties by value, like in your example, you would have to return something and then apply it to the object from the outside, if you need to change the object properties. Of course you could always pass the properties themselves as references.

Anyway, I would use the first approach (passing the whole object), because it is more readable, and more extensible if you need to add properties later. The memory impact is minimal since only the pointer to the object is copied, and not the value for each of the properties you need.

Comment: Very constuctive explanation. Just as I've expected to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: But now your function needs knowledge of how the object is constructed. What if you want to use it with other objects? It will need knowledge of how they are constructed too. Best to implement an interface probably.

Comment: I think that if I'd like to pass another object to this function this object should have the same structure so the function can work with objects of certain structure only.

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to agree with Mihai, because usually we underestimate the usefulness of both the object properties and the function, but if we really want elegant code, the function parameters should reflect the function purpose (and the overall data model).  Having said that, it's a good argument for making the function a method on the object itself, but assuming it's a utility function:

```
  function find_median($low, $high) {

     return ($low + $high)/2;

  }
```

And our object is called UserStats, holding several arrays of that user's stats in various areas.  It wouldn't be criminal or kill puppies to pass in the whole object (or even just the whole array of the specific stat group), but it would be lazy, I think, and ultimately lead to a simple function becoming a bloated calculator because "well heck, it already has all the data, may as well do it all here!"

All of this is my take on coding, which is that it should reflect the actual model and workflow as elegantly, simply, and cleverly as possible. I'll try to make this meet with efficiency and performance, but at the end of the day, I want code that tells a story, draws a map, shows what is really going on more than code that lobs objects and arrays around rather than gets what it needs.

Having said all of that, maybe you do want a calculator, etc, and like Mihal said, it's much more common to need a value and not have it than it is to have just the data you need, no more no less.